# Async function does not wait for await function to end

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

i have an async function that do not work as expected, here is the code :

```js
const onCreateCoachSession = async (event, context) => {
  const { coachSessionID } = context.params;
  let coachSession = event.val();

  let opentokSessionId = 'prout';

  await opentok.createSession({ mediaMode: 'relayed' }, function(
    error,
    session
  ) {
    if (error) {
      console.log('Error creating session:', error);
    } else {
      opentokSessionId = session.sessionId;
      console.log('opentokSessionIdBefore: ', opentokSessionId);
      const sessionId = session.sessionId;
      console.log('Session ID: ' + sessionId);
      coachSession.tokbox = {
        archiving: true,
        sessionID: sessionId,
        sessionIsCreated: true,
      };
      db.ref(`coachSessions/${coachSessionID}`).update(coachSession);
    }
  });
  console.log('opentokSessionIdEnd: ', opentokSessionId);
};
```

My function onCreateCoachSession trigger on a firebase event (it's a cloud function), but it does not end for opentok.createSession to end, i don't understand why as i put an await before.

Can anyone have an idea why my code trigger directly the last console log (opentokSessionIdEnd)

Here is a screenshot on order of console.log : 
[image]

It's probably a simple problem of async/await that i missed but i cannot see what.

I thanks in advance the community for the help.

Comment: Then `opentok.createSession` doesn't return a `Promise` (or anything `.then`able)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `createSession` in callback mode (you're giving it a callback function), so it doesn't return a Promise, so it can't be `await`ed.

Two solutions :

1/ Use createSession in Promise mode (if it allows this, see the doc)

```
let session = null;

try{
    session = await opentok.createSession({ mediaMode: 'relayed' })
} catch(err) {
    console.log('Error creating session:', error);
}
```

or 2/ await a Promise

```
let session;

try {
    session = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        opentok.createSession({ mediaMode: 'relayed' }, (error, session) => {
            if (error) {
                return reject(error)
            }
            resolve(session);
        })
    })
} catch (err) {
    console.log('Error creating session:', err);
    throw new Error(err);
}

opentokSessionId = session.sessionId;
console.log('opentokSessionIdBefore: ', opentokSessionId);
// ...
```

Comment: Yes, why? So we fall in the `catch(err)`

Comment: `reject()` doesn't return anything. And it wouldn't make much sense in the first place. Just use an `else`

Comment: It's true `return` isn't really useful here, it's merely to end the function. But it doesn't hurt. I could have written `reject(error);return;`, again, just to make sure the function ends here.

Comment: Or simply use a construct that allows to execute two different branches depending on a condition. Like `if ... else ...`

Comment: Yes, it's another perfectly valid and more common construct :)

Answer (score 0):

await means it will wait till the promise is resolved. I guess there is no promise returned in this case. you can create your own promise and handle the case

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer